# best way to drill through a window beam

Tags: drill, steel

having big problems trying to drill through a reinforced lintel to hang some brackets, i presume the concrete lintel has steel in but using a hss drill bit fails - which are the best type of drill bits to use, technique and which ones are the best.

thanks

Comment: Before drilling into a critical load-bearing part of your house, perhaps you could look for some other method to attach the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when putting up curtain brackets and hit a steel lintel. I was recommended 135deg split point cobalt and a good metal cutting paste. I must say I am well impressed with results.

I was also advised :

1. Drill slow
2. Use light pressure
3. Use cutting paste
4. Stop every 10 seconds to give the bit a chance to cool down

Answer (score 0):

You need a carbide drill bit [like this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Bosch-1-4-in-x-6-in-BlueGranite-Turbo-Carbide-Hammer-Drill-Bit-HCBG06T/100001488?MERCH=REC-_-SearchPLPHorizontal1_rr-_-NA-_-100001488-_-N). High speed steel will dull quickly. A hammer drill would also help but I have cut small holes with a regular drill motor in the past really hard on the drill bumping it constantly to simulate the hammer action.

Comment: That is perfect to get through the concrete, but if he's really hitting steel then HSS will be better at that point.

Comment: I wouldn't use a "hammer anything" on a reinforced concrete lintel. That lintel is designed with a certain amount of bonding around that reinforcing and the hammer action could crack/loosen the concrete from the rebar.  I'm sure it's over designed, but why push it.